# Sorting UK dates using tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, datefilter

I'm using [TableSorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/) to sort a table, as I am trying to replace datatables (as it struggles with large data sets). I am using the following Javascript:

```
$('#tableID').tablesorter({
    widgets: ["saveSort"] ,
    dateFormat : "dd/mm/yyyy" // set the default date format
});
```

It doesn't work. If I sort on one of the dates columns it sorts as below

- 23/08/2019
- 30/04/2019
- 11/08/2019

That's not even sorting numerically so i am a but stumped. I also tried using dateformat: 'uk' with no luck

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just a note regarding struggling with large datasets; that's a JS problem, not a DataTables one. You're likely to have the same issue with TS. I'd suggest using server side filtering and paging if you have a lot of data to display.

Comment: Also, have you seen this page of their documentation? https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-date-format.html

Comment: `datatables` doesn't have any problem with large data sets, I'm using it for thousands of results and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks Rory. The issue with datatables is that it was taking a long time to rendering as there could be up to 2,000 records at times. I am testing this sorting on a table of three records so i doubt its the same issue but thanks for your reply

Comment: Datatables doesnt have issues when it renders but sometimes crashes the browser trying to render otherwise just takes a long time to load up

Comment: TableSorter will have the same issue. In either case, the answer to your sorting question is in the link I posted in my second comment.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just found the issue the date format should have been 'ddmmyyyy' rather than 'dd/mm/yyyy'

I must have just needed to rubber duck it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are supposed to type the format without slashes in your JS, but keep it with slashes in your HTML file. In your case:

```
dateFormat : "ddmmyyyy" // set the default date format
```

Read more about this particular question it in the official documentation, it has a great example as well:
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-date-format.html

Comment: Thanks Artur, i just came to the same solution. Thanks for responding